# Workflow from HDFS to Dashboard and which tools to use:

Tags: python, mongodb, hadoop, hive, apache-pig

We have data in HDFS(Text format), data will be updated daily, weekly and Monthly.
We have to analyze  data from HDFS and display the analysis and stats on UI.

Can someone please provide suggestion on how to approach this.
Tools that we can use is: Hive, Pig, MongoDB, Python, R, Spark(open to other tools as well)

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is an *extremely* broad question.  The more specific and detailed your question is, the more likely it will get answered.

Comment: What is the best way we can query data from HDFS(Using Hive or Pig)?
we need to store the queried result(query using Hive/Pig) and then perform certain analysis on result and need to show the 
stats to client on UI. Where should we store result, in HDFS or elastics search so that we can display the analysis on UI at the
run time or within minimum time possible.
We are planning to do the analysis using R programming.
Please provide your valuable suggestions.

Thanks,